# Open subsets of perfect Polish spaces

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that every non-empty open subset of a perfect Polish space
is uncountable?

It is true that the space itself is uncountable but I was not able to show 
that every non-empty open subset is uncountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G_\delta$-sets in a completely metrizable space are completely metrizable, so the same is certainly true of open sets. An open subset of a separable metrizable space is also separable and metrizable. Finally, a non-empty open subset of a perfect space is perfect: an isolated point in it would be isolated in the whole space. Thus, every non-empty subset of a perfect Polish space is a perfect Polish space and therefore has cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Why is this open set complete?

Comment: @Evelyn: It isn’t complete in the same metric (unless it’s actually a clopen set), but it’s completely metrizable. It’s a standard result, not just for open subsets of completely metrizable spaces, but for $G_\delta$ subsets.

Comment: Aha, I see now, I was confused about this point. Than you very much.

Comment: @Evelyn: You’re very welcome.